# google vision OCR Arabic text detection

Tags: android, ocr, google-vision

I am using google vision API for text detection and I get the expected result for English but when test on Arabic I get no result, I found in google decumentation that it support many languages includes Arabic by using parameter languagehint ar 
but i don't know where to use this parameter.
I use this [tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2016/11/optical-character-recognition-android-ocr/).

Answer (score 2):

Till the date Google Mobile Vision API does not support Arabic language. Please refer below link

https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview